# Setting Up a Public Git Repo

Tags: git

my team has been working on a platform for the past few months, and we're ready to release it to the rest of the firm.  We'd like to follow the "integration manager workflow" found here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows.

We have some proprietary code in our team repository that we'd rather not share with the rest of the firm, and so must create a "stripped-down" version of our current team repository.  I'm looking at doing the following:

1. clone our existing team repository to create the "integration
   manager repo"
2. `rm` all the proprietary files
3. `commit` the rms
4. `rebase -i --root` to squash all commits and prevent rewinds
5. `clone --bare` the "integration manager repo" to create the "blessed repo"

Now, being relatively inexperienced with Git, a couple of things are uncertain to me about this approach:

1. Can I still do a pull from the "blessed repo" into our team repo?
2. Assuming that I can do #1, I think the rms will get pulled, deleting all of our proprietary files.  I need Git to view our team repo's more-advanced state as a child state of the blessed repo state.  Is this something that I can do with rebase?
3. As we continue to work on the platform, we will commit to our team repo a mixture of "public" features and proprietary features.  What is the best way to push only the "public" features?  Can I `rebase` to change the order of commits so that all "public" feature commits are at the front of the commit history, and then git push only up to the SHA of the latest "public" feature commit?

Thanks in advance for the help... I wanted to run this by some more experienced Git users before making such big changes.

**UPDATE**
Sorry, I wasn't being clear...  steps 2, 3 and 4 were all meant to be applied to the "integration manager repo".  In any case, I read up some more on `rebase` and decided that it wasn't a good idea to `rebase` our team's shared repository every time we made a "public" change.

What I ended up doing instead of steps 2, 3 and 4 was `rm` the .git folder in the "integration manager repo", and start over fresh with `git init`.  Then I pulled from this fresh "integration manager repo" and merged with our team's repo, using the `-s ours` flag since our team's version is a superset.  Now our team repo and the public repo have a common commit.  I created a "public" branch in our team repo and pointed it to this common commit.  Going forward, whenever we make a public change, we will need to cherry-pick it into this "public" branch and then pull the public branch into the "integration manager repo".

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to `pull` changes from the blessed repo to the team one (as they're `rebase`d), but you may be able to `cherry-pick` them. Of course, conflicts would probably be part of your routine.

As you've squashed your `rm`s, your blessed repo will never see those `rm`s performed at all. So, whenever you `cherry-pick` those commits into your team repo, you will just have files that never change (and the troubles that can generate).

The problem will be publishing changes back from the team repo to the blessed one :)

If I were you (well, some time ago I was in a similar position), I would think in creating any kind of script that moves changes from one repository to the other. When going from the blessed one to the team one, make some warning about related rm'ed files you probably want to see based on the files that were changed (if any). When going back, exclude changes to rm'ed files.

Anyway, I don't think this is a good idea at all. Triple check before going wild - maybe start with babysteps?

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks - your comment made me think things through again and I think I found a better solution.

Comment: @piyopiyo13: share it, so we all learn :) Glad to see it helped.